# Unity show audio spectrum(wave) when upload audio file

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I am trying to implement a spectrum of audio files that are part of Samsung's voice recording capabilities.

Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6Fvt.png)

But, there is information showing the spectrum in real time, but there is no information showing the wave of the uploaded audio file.

Answer (score 1):

What you are likely looking for is to display the overall amplitude of the audio data that you are getting. The data you get from Unity with GetSpectrumData however is an array showing the amplitude at a bunch of different frequencies. To find a suitable "overall" amplitude, you could either average, find the max, or sum up the contents of this array, then use this new value to draw your visualization. I'd probably go with finding the maximum, i.e. the highest/loudest value in the array. You could do this by using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;
/*...*/
float loudest = yourSpectrumDataArray.Max();
```

Note also that the amplitude values you get from GetSpectrumData are tiiiiny, and you might want to convert them to decibel values before working with them. I'm using this equation - can't remember where I found it but it works for me:

```
public float AmplitudeToDB(float value)
{
    return 20.0f * Mathf.Log10(value / 2.5f + 1.5849e-13f);
}
```